# pageyoffset just stays blank

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script below, the page offset just remains blank eventhough the scrollbar has been moved. please help

```
<script>
var  menu, yPos;
function yScroll(){


    menu = document.getElementById('Menu');
    menu = document.getElementById('cpBtn');
    yPos = document.pageYOffset;


    if(yPos > 150)
    {

    menu.style.position="fixed";
    menu.style.top="0px";

    }
    else
    {
    menu.style.position="relative";
    menu.style.background="red";


    }
    alert(yPos);
}
document.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
</script>
```

Comment: as in, the alert doesn't pop up or it pops up but still says 0?

Comment: Don't use alert to debug, use the console.

Comment: shouldn't it be window and not document for pageYOffset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
 yPos = window.pageYOffset;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwv3e7qr/